# Google Plusone button overlay / popup wrong positioning

Tags: html, css, qtip, google-plus-one, qtip2

I have the **google plusone button** inside a [jquery qtip tooltip](http://qtip2.com/) and the **overlay / popup** that comes saying "You have publicly recommended this" **is showing on the top of the page**.
If I move the plusone button outside the tooltip it renders perfectly.

Can I fix this to show properly even inside the qtip?

Screenshot: http://phtr.co/H6T7aB

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @SatishGandham Nope, I left it as it is.